# Android Volley onErrorResponse not giving error

Tags: android, android-volley

I am trying to use volley for my user login and registration but have encountered a problem when trying to login or register. The server I am trying to connect to is on my localhost and it is turned on and working, I am able to access it from other applications.

When I enter in the credentials for login/register and press the button I get a log saying that the error message is null. The issue is that the application doesnt crash and the log cat doesnt point to any lines causing the error, so I have no idea really whats going wrong.

I have tried the different volley error methods like `error.networkResponse`and a few other to try get more information but none return any information.

I have looked at other solutions on the site to people experiencing similar problems but nothing seems to work.

Can anyone explain to me why I am getting this error?

**Log cat log**

```
Login Error: null
```

**Class printing the log - LoginActivity**

```
import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.android.volley.Request.Method;
    import com.android.volley.Response;
    import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;

    import com.example.rory.pocketchef.R;
    import com.example.rory.pocketchef.app.AppConfig;
    import com.example.rory.pocketchef.app.AppController;
    import com.example.rory.pocketchef.helper.SQLiteHandler;
    import com.example.rory.pocketchef.helper.SessionManager;

    public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
        private static final String TAG = RegisterActivity.class.getSimpleName();
        private Button btnLogin;
        private Button btnLinkToRegister;
        private EditText inputEmail;
        private EditText inputPassword;
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        private SessionManager session;
        private SQLiteHandler db;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

            inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
            inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
            btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
            btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);

            // Progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);

            // SQLite database handler
            db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

            // Session manager
            session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

            // Check if user is already logged in or not
            if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
                // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, FirstActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }

            // Login button Click Event
            btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                    String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();

                    // Check for empty data in the form
                    if (!email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
                        // login user
                        checkLogin(email, password);
                    } else {
                        // Prompt user to enter credentials
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Please enter the credentials!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                }

            });

            // Link to Register Screen
            btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            RegisterActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
            });

        }

        /**
         * function to verify login details in mysql db
         * */
        private void checkLogin(final String email, final String password) {
            // Tag used to cancel the request
            String tag_string_req = "req_login";

            pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
            showDialog();

            StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
                    AppConfig.URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
                    hideDialog();

                    try {
                        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                        // Check for error node in json
                        if (!error) {
                            // user successfully logged in
                            // Create login session
                            session.setLogin(true);

                            // Now store the user in SQLite
                            String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                            JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                            String name = user.getString("name");
                            String email = user.getString("email");
                            String created_at = user
                                    .getString("created_at");

                            // Inserting row in users table
                            db.addUser(name, email, uid, created_at);

                            // Launch main activity
                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, FirstActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            // Error in login. Get the error message
                            String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // JSON error
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    hideDialog();
                }
            }) {

                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    // Posting parameters to login url
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("email", email);
                    params.put("password", password);

                    return params;
                }

            };

            // Adding request to request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
        }

        private void showDialog() {
            if (!pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.show();
        }

        private void hideDialog() {
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

**AppController Class**

```
import android.app.Application;
    import android.text.TextUtils;

    import com.android.volley.Request;
    import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

    public class AppController extends Application {

        public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

        private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

        private static AppController mInstance;

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            mInstance = this;
        }

        public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
            return mInstance;
        }

        public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
            if (mRequestQueue == null) {
                mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
            }

            return mRequestQueue;
        }

        public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
            req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
            getRequestQueue().add(req);
        }

        public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
            req.setTag(TAG);
            getRequestQueue().add(req);
        }

        public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
            if (mRequestQueue != null) {
                mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.rory.pocketchef" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <android:uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <android:uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <android:uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


    <application
        android:name=".app.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SingleRecipeDisplay"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_single_recipe_display"
            android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Favourites" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Help" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.RegisterActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.LoginActivity">
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Log Cat when trying to register, (Same result for login attempts)**

```
02-25 12:09:19.558 20001-20001/com.example.rory.loginandregistration E/RegisterActivity: Login Error: null
02-25 12:09:19.579 20001-20001/com.example.rory.loginandregistration D/Volley: [1] Request.finish: 7636 ms: [ ] http://178.167.255.22:8886/android_login_api/login.php 0x1d219ab4 NORMAL 1
```

**Log Cat Print Stack**

```
02-25 12:28:17.680 9729-9729/com.example.rory.pocketchef W/System.err: com.android.volley.TimeoutError
02-25 12:28:17.680 9729-9729/com.example.rory.pocketchef W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:147)
02-25 12:28:17.680 9729-9729/com.example.rory.pocketchef W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:114)
02-25 12:28:28.391 9729-9743/com.example.rory.pocketchef I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 32313(1656KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(40KB) LOS objects, 35% free, 15MB/23MB, paused 9.512ms total 135.206ms
```

Comment: What's your url ? are you on emulateur ?

Comment: `error.getMessage()` returns null? `error` itself isn't null?

Comment: The error.getMessage() prints `null`, my URL is my IP address is my IP address followed by `:8888/android_login_api/login.php` but I have triple checked this and know it is correct

Comment: When you say you can access it with other app, you mean other android app ? If you use a device to try your server and if your device is connected to same wifi spot as your computer, your ip is something like 192.x.x.x right ? you said your server is local

Comment: Well I am trying to implement a user login and register function, so I followed a tutorial to make this and got it working fine and now I am trying to add it to an existing app and this is when I started getting the error. Yea I have tried all the usual stuff with IP address and making sure everything is connect correctly but no joy

Comment: Does you php application receive the android post request for login? Moreover what's the class of VolleyError ('error.getClass()')? If it is TimeoutError.class probably has nothing to show in its message hence its null.

Comment: The result from the `.getClass()` is actually a time out error, any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getMessage()` can be null sometimes. This is how I read volley onErrorResponse(), volley has direct/sub direct exception classes as follows

> Known Direct Subclasses
>   AuthFailureError, NetworkError, ParseError, ServerError, TimeoutError
>
> Known Indirect Subclasses
>   NoConnectionError

check particular error using `instanceOf`

```
if(error instanceof TimeOutError)
   *show timeout error occured*
else if(error instanceof ServerError)
   *show server error occured*
same for others
```

> I have tried the different volley error methods like error.networkResponse

Yes this is good to read error response also, well you can be sure that what exactly happened at server end. (server must return error response when error occurred on server side) 
*Do not forget to read*
`error.networkResponse.statusCode` also.

To get more info on this visit [Java doc VolleyError](http://javadocs.okadatech.com/javadoc/volley/reference/com/android/volley/VolleyError.html)

**UPDATED**
While working on local machine server : things to keep in mind

1. Always use System IP Address (instead of localhost)
2. Make sure local path is correct.
3. Always test **API/urls** on browser or check with [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) and move to Android Project.
   while testing with these things you solve many server errors.

Comment: after running `error.getClass()` i have seen that it is a `TimeoutError`, any suggestions as to how to solve this?

Comment: Retry the request and set more time to Request Connection TimeOut

Comment: I tried setting more time but still times out, I have updated the question with the logcat result when an fail register occurs

Comment: which`VolleyException`  it is throwing... and post the stacktrace also.. `volleyError.printStackTrace();`

Comment: oops. :( I tried to hit http://178.167.255.22:8886/android_login_api/login.php in browser and guess what, I get `ConnectionTimeout` error. I think something is wrong at server end.

Comment: I am hosting the server locally on my machine so I dont think you would be able to connect anyway, but when I click on it it doesnt seem to load and just says `connecting`. How to i print the stack trace to the log?

Comment: I taught its public server :)...  `public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {  error.printStackTrace();  }` result will print in `logcat` tab.

Comment: Ok I updated the question to show the print stack results, I really appreciate the help as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104536/discussion-between-bharat-and-jjsmith).

Comment: Your if, else if code is quite verbose; I accomplished the same with the same old Log.e("ERR", String.valueOf(error));

Answer (score 2):

After many different failed attempts and with the help of bharat, I have found the issue to the problem.

I was using the wrong IP address in the volley commands. I wasnt using the machines IP address which is found by typing `ifconfig` into the command line. Adding the correct IP address was the solution.

So warning to anyone else with the same problem, use `ifcong` to find the IP address and not a Google search for `Whats my IP` as this will not return the machines IP address.