# android apps adding data to mysql database throws JSONException

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I'm trying to add a row in a table PERSON(nom,pass_world) in mysql database using an android apps.
when i execute php code (**savedata.php**) in the browser it shows me : query_result":"SUCCESS", which means that a row is successefly added.
i search in google for some code that allows an android app to add data to mysql database then i tryed it, but unfortunately it throws JSONEexcption and shows message "Error parsing JSON data" as you can see in the code below:

**savedata.php**

```html
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","othmane");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
   echo '{"query_result":"ERROR"}';
}

$name = $_GET['nom'];
$pass = $_GET['pass_world'];
 
$result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO person (nom,pass_world) VALUES ('$name', '$pass')");
 
if($result == true) {
    echo '{"query_result":"SUCCESS"}';
}
else{
    echo '{"query_result":"FAILURE"}';
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText inputName;
EditText inputpwd;
Button button;
String nom, password;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    inputName = (EditText) (findViewById(R.id.editText));
    inputpwd = (EditText) (findViewById(R.id.editText2));
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
}

public void save(View view) {
    nom = inputName.getText().toString();
    password = inputpwd.getText().toString();

    new SignupActivity(this).execute(nom, password);
}
```

}

**SignupAtivity.java**

```
public class SignupActivity extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

private Context context;

public SignupActivity(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

protected void onPreExecute() {

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String link;
    String data;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    String result;

    try {
        data = "?nom=jean";
        data += "&pass_world=123456";

        link = "http://localhost/save/savedata.php" + data;
        URL url = new URL(link);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        result = bufferedReader.readLine();
        return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    String jsonStr = result;
    if (jsonStr != null) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
            String query_result = jsonObj.getString("query_result");
            if (query_result.equals("SUCCESS")) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Data inserted successfully. Signup successfull.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (query_result.equals("FAILURE")) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Data could not be inserted. Signup failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Couldn't connect to remote database.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(context,"Error parsing JSON data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Couldn't get any JSON data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

}

log cat :

03-07 06:42:26.992 8503-8503/com.example.othmane.myapplication D/!!: Exception: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 80): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
03-07 06:42:29.844 8503-8503/com.example.othmane.myapplication W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value Exception of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
03-07 06:42:29.845 8503-8503/com.example.othmane.myapplication W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
03-07 06:42:29.845 8503-8503/com.example.othmane.myapplication W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:160)
03-07 06:42:29.845 8503-8503/com.example.othmane.myapplication W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:173)
03-07 06:42:29.845 8503-8503/com.example.othmane.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.example.othmane.myapplication.SignupActivity.onPostExecute(SignupActivity.java:60)
03-07 06:42:29.845 8503-8503/com.example.othmane.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.example.othmane.myapplication.SignupActivity.onPostExecute(SignupActivity.java:20)
03-07 06:42:29.845 8503-8503/com.example.othmane.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
03-07 06:42:29.845 8503-8503/com.example.othmane.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
03-07 06:42:29.845 8503-8503/com.example.othmane.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
03-07 06:42:29.846 8503-8503/com.example.othmane.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-07 06:42:29.847 8503-8503/com.example.othmane.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
03-07 06:42:29.847 8503-8503/com.example.othmane.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
03-07 06:42:29.847 8503-8503/com.example.othmane.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-07 06:42:29.847 8503-8503/com.example.othmane.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
03-07 06:42:29.847 8503-8503/com.example.othmane.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
03-07 06:42:29.847 8503-8503/com.example.othmane.myapplication D/!!: Exception: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 80): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

Comment: check what value you are getting here `jsonStr`.. and post logcat of JSONException..

Comment: i make edit on post to show the log cat

Comment: what is the response (jsonStr) value..

Comment: when i do Log.d("value : ", jsonStr) it shows : 
Exception: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 80): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

Comment: do you know the cause of that ?

Comment: check updated comments : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35561957/android-volley-onerrorresponse-not-giving-error/35570244#35570244

Comment: let me know it doesn't help..

Comment: Thank you , i just had to use my computer ip network address instead of localhost.

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention  IP Address of server which providing the POST service.

```
link = "http://localhost/save/savedata.php" + data;
```

make it as

```
link = "http://<IP ADDRESS : PORT>/save/savedata.php" + data;
```